# Excel VBA Add Comment from Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, comments

I do not understand why the below does not add comments from A1 to A27 :(

```
Dim aComment As String

aComment = Split("ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL", "|")

For i = 1 To i = 27
    For x = LBound(aComment) To UBound(aComment)
        With Worksheets("report").Range(Cells(1, i)).AddComment
            .Visible = False
            .Text aComment(x)
        End With
    Next
Next
```

It would be amazing if you could give me a hand, know I am nearly there, but cannot figure out what I got wrong :(

Comment: Even if we correct the syntax: `Dim aComment() As String` and `For i = 1 To 27`. There is a logical problem too. You want to add 4 comments each to the cells A1:A27? This is not possible. Only one comment per cell is possible.

Comment: HI Axel, not 4 comment per cell, only one per cell: ABC in A1, DEF in B1, GHI in C1 etc.

Comment: You only have 4 comments, what will you put on the rest?

Comment: I only put 4 comments so that there is no clutter, I have 27 different values, but they are rather long, so I replaced them with ABC etc. If easier we can change From i = 1 To i = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if you want to add the comments from A1:A4.

```
Dim aComment As Variant, i As Long

aComment = Split("ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL", "|")

For i = 1 To 4
    Sheets("report").Range("A" & i).AddComment(aComment(i - 1)).Visible = False
    'Sheets("report").Cells(1, i).).AddComment(aComment(i - 1)).Visible = False
Next
```

As for the things to improve to make it work:

1. You need to declare `aComment` as `Variant` and not `String`.
2. Just use one Loop and a one liner statement.
3. And you need to fix your `For Loop Syntax` from `For i = 1 To i = 27` to `For i = 1 To 27`

I only use `4` in the loop since you only gave four samples. You can adjust it to suit.
Also I'm confused. In your question you want to put it in `A1:A27` but in comment A1 to D1.
Regardless I provide code for both.

Comment: Amazing! Even simpler than I had thought. Yes, Cells(1, i) works as intended.